# Inspect element that only appear when other element is mouse overed/entered

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Often I want to inspect an element (e.g. tooltip) that only appears when another element is mouse overed/entered.  The element that appears, is made visible via jQuery's mouseenter event.

I can't inspect the tooltip, since the tooltip disappears when my mouse leaves the containing element.

Is there a way to pause JS events so I could hover on the element, then pause the browser's JS, and successfully inspect it?

For an example, try inspecting Twitter bootstrap's tooltips: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips.

Comment: Just FYI, if the element appears because of CSS instead of JS, you can force a `:hover` on it by right clicking on the element in the Elements (DOM) view in Dev Tools, selecting "Force Element State" and then ":hover".

Answer (score 231, accepted):

It's fairly easy in Chrome 38.0.2094.0.

Here's what it'll look like:
[image]

Step-by-step:

1. Open the DevTools in the Sources panel
2. Make the tooltip appear by hovering over the button
3. Press F8 to freeze the page
4. Switch to the Elements panel and use the magnifying glass icon in the top left to select the tooltip

If the tooltip shows up because of CSS, here's what you can do in that case:
[image]

Step-by-step:

1. Open the DevTools
2. Select the triggering element in the dev tools (the link)
3. Right click, and select "force element state", and select ":hover"
4. Inspect the CSS tooltip

Comment: Then switch back to Elements and locate the source for the tooltip in HTML (because I don't think in this mode interactive "Inspect Element" is available)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter It's available via the spyglass icon in the top left. Just click on the icon, then click on the tooltip :)

Comment: Yeah, I added a GIF to make it easier to see what I'm doing.

Comment: Wait... not to be off topic but how did you make a gif of a screenshot that easily???

Comment: @DonnyP I used `byzanz-record`. It's a package you can get with `sudo apt-get install byzanz`.

Comment: There's also [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/), it records a portion of the screen directly in a super-optimized GIF. Windows, OS X and Linux.

Comment: I am a developer & I use FF, any way to do the same in that.

Comment: @VenomVendor: FF has exactly the same feature, it's also assigned to F8.

Comment: What's the keyboard shortcut for OS X? It's not F8 and hovering over the pause icon in the debugger shows that you should use `%s`, which seems to be a format string. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Vtagxzi.png

Comment: @SomeGuy I guess there was something wrong with my chrome version as the text has been changed to `F8` and it works now. ;)

Comment: @bfred.it LICEcap is *not* available for Linux. [See this Github issue](https://github.com/lepht/licecap/issues/1) on the topic. Seems folks are having success running it with [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/).

Answer (score 15):

Both Safari's and Chrome's Web Inspector offers checkboxes where you can toggle the `:active`, `:focus`, `:hover` and `:visited` state of an element. Using those might be even easier.

Safari:

[image: The checkboxes in Safari]

Chrome:

[image: The checkboxes in Chrome]

Comment: The tooltip isn't triggered by `:hover` styles.

Comment: Firebug on Firefox has the same thing (minus `:visited`, which is restricted to prevent snooping) - on the HTML tab, it's in the "Style" dropdown on the right

Comment: @Izkata For Firefox's native developer tools, right-click the element in the breadcrumbs, or the HTML/DOM tree, and pick from `:hover`, `:active` or `:focus`.

Answer (score 4):

There's also another tricky way to do it :

1. Go over the element which makes your tooltip appear.
2. Right click to open the contextual menu.
3. Move your mouse to your dev tool window and left click anywhere in the dev tool panel.

Your tooltip will stay visible, you will then be able to inspect it in the Element tab.

Tested on Chrome. Doesn't seem to work on Firefox.

Comment: This is how I have done it in the past, but @SomeGuy's answer is the best and easiest way.

Comment: @JohnDubya No it's really not. It may be the official way but it's certainly not easier. There are far too many steps involved.

Comment: This is what I normally do, but it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 3):

While [@SomeGuy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24790135/2685386) is excellent (t-up for animated gifs), as an alternative you can always do it programmatically. Just pop open the console and type in the event name

```
document.getElementById('id').dispatchEvent(new Event('event-type'));
```

(with pure javascript specific syntax may vary by browser)

Even easier with jQuery:

```
$('#id').trigger('event-type');
```

In your example (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), open the console and type in, for example:

```
$("button:contains('Tooltip on right')").mouseenter();
```

And the tooltip appears in the DOM and can be manually inspected/modified:

```
<div style="top: 14406.9px; left: 1048.25px; display: block;"
id="tooltip952596" class="tooltip fade right in" role="tooltip">
<div style="" class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
<div class="tooltip-inner">Tooltip on right</div></div>
```

---

As in the comments, if you move the mouse pointer over the page frame, you can trigger other events such as `mouseout`. To prevent this you can press <kbd>F8</kbd> (as in the acc. answer) or type `debugger;` (which is its script equivalent)

Comment: Whilst inspecting the element you can still trigger other events (like `mouseout`), so it doesn't solve the problem in the first place. You have to be quite careful when selecting it. But it is an alternative approach.