# Kendo UI Gantt - How to hide tooltip that shows up when you hover tasks

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-gantt

I need to hide tooltip that shows up when you hover tasks.
The rectangular tooltip that includes task title, percentage complete, start and end date.

Answer (score 0):

The hard part was to inspect a tag that hides when mouse leaves.
I followed the steps at [Inspect element that only appear when other element is mouse overed/entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790002/inspect-element-that-only-appear-when-other-element-is-mouse-overed-entered) to inspect the element and come up with the following css rule:

```
.k-gantt-timeline .k-widget.k-tooltip {
display: none;
}
```